# Update mysql table in case if computer is shutdown

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am developing chatting system in codeigniter and mysql, i create log table for display online users and offline user, all is well but problem is that in case computer is  shutdown due to any reason like power off etc. that user should be offline, is it possible to update mysql table

Comment: store data locally when offline. For example in localStorage, then transfer it to mysql when online then clear your localStorage..

Comment: I'd say you would have to implement some method of polling the clients at an interval. When no response is returned, treat it as "offline".

Comment: Write an ajax request that executes every 30 seconds, if user X has not sent that request in the past 60 seconds, it means he's offline.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the easiest way to do this is showing a user offline when a certain threshold of a time interval has passed when the client has not made a request to the server.